# xelatex, luatex issues when building pdf of demo book

Tags: r, bookdown, xelatex

I can build the gitbook of the demo just fine.

If I attempt to build a pdf, the .tex file is made by pandoc, but xelatex compilation bombs.  I get a message in the Build window that's incomplete.

If I manually compile in the shell, I get the following output.  Short story-- it would seem that there's code somewhere, probably in pandoc, that uses 
\xetex_if_engine:F and
\luatex_if_engine:TF
which apparently have been non-functional since 1-1-2017.

But I can't be the first person to try to compile a pdf since January.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a similar issue to one reported to the bookdown Github repo, and please see if my reply helps: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/375#issuecomment-288462901

Comment: Yes, updating packages and FNDB worked.  Thanks for the diagnosis and solution!

Answer (score 0):

The LaTeX log shows `LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>`, which is too old, and you will need to refresh your filename database (FNDB) as instructed [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/375#issuecomment-288462901),